# Will the new Ubuntu softwarfe for desktops work just as well if installed on a laptop?

Tags: laptop

It has been awhile since I have had a computer to use, years in fact. Back then I was using Ubuntu on a laptop, but now that I have come to use it again all I see is a desktop version and not a laptop version. Will it work just the same if I download the desktop version for a laptop??

Comment: There's no difference. And Ubuntu is not "a software", it's a full fledged Operating System made out of thousands (or more) of softwares working together.

Comment: Yes! The desktop version works for desktops, laptops, all-in-ones, two-in-ones, three-in-ones, Intel based tablets etc. You may consider the server version if you are an admin of a server.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 2 versions of the distro:

- Server version, for server use, without the "useless" packages (from a server point of view), like X/Gnome/KDE etc... , and default install of all server-related packages like Apache, Bind9, etc... The installation process for the server version is CUI only (of course).
- Desktop version, for everything else (from desktop to tablet to smartphone to Raspberry pi).

So don't freak out, you can take the desktop version on your laptop, it'll be fine!